# How to avoid livewire request for simple inputs calculations?

Tags: laravel, laravel-livewire

How would I avoid doing calculation for 3 inputs using Livewire and use JS instead, but still can bind the inputs and their new values with the component.

**Example:**

```
                <input id="cash-price"
                        type="text"
                       wire:model="total_cache_price"
                       class="amount-credit">

                <input id="deposit"
                       type="text"
                       wire:model="deposit"
                       class="amount-credit">

                <input id="trade-in"
                       type="text"
                       wire:model="trade_in"
                       class="amount-credit">
```

I can easily do a simple calculation using JS, but the properties in Livewire component would still be empty or null after submitting the form. I am trying to avoid livewire requests for every input change.

**Note:** I understand the deferred updating in livewire, the problem is with the property values not changing.

Comment: can you share the blade component and how are you trying to achieve this with Livewire and can´t update the properties?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I will show you an example in alpine js + livewire way.
Here I want to set value in two inputs from a selected option in select.
Please note that x-ref is used in alpine to directly access DOM elements without using `getElementById`.

```
<div x-data="{
from_date : @entangle('from_date').defer,
to_date : @entangle('to_date').defer,
dateChange(){
    select = this.$refs.years;
    this.from_date = select.options[select.selectedIndex].getAttribute('data-from');
    this.to_date = select.options[select.selectedIndex].getAttribute('data-to');
},
resetFilters(){
    this.net_balances = false;
}}">
<select x-ref="years" @change="dateChange()">
    <option value="">Year</option>
    @foreach ($years as $key => $year)
    <option wire:key="{{ 'years'.$key }}" data-from="{{ $year->from_date }}" data-to="{{ $year->to_date }}" value="{{ $year->id }}">{{ $year->name }} </option>
    @endforeach
</select>
<div>
    <text type="date" x-model="from_date" />
</div>
<div >
    <text type="date" x-model="to_date" />
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you, unfortunately I am new to alpine and didn't use it within my project yet, but I appreciate the help.